# Multiple delimiters in Ruby File IO

Tags: ruby, file-io, delimiter

Suppose there is this text file:

```
abcd,efgh,ijkl  mnop,qrst
12345,78    poqs,90st
```

I want to read strings until `","` or `"\t"` or `"\n"`, whichever comes first.

Is there any Ruby method to do this?

Comment: may be you can try this: "String".scan(/\w+/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this would work:

```
open('file.txt').read.split(/\t\n,/)
```

Basically open the file, take the string output of the file and split on tab, newline or comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.read('file.txt').scan(/\w+/)
```

It will scan all words no matter what delimiter.